# What do you look for when renting a photography studio (uk)

Tags: studio, renting

I am currently putting together a business plan for a large photography studio, and am trying to get my head around the dramatic variation in studio day rates in the UK.

I have seen day rates from £100 to £1000, mostly it seems related to 3 statistics - Location, general studio quality, and size. (I am not including any equipment rental in this)

So does anyone have any personal experience on studio rental? what do you look for? what will you pay more for? lets say 2 studios are the same size and a similar location, what would sway you either way?

Comment: Lighting and backdrop equipment included with the rental fee.

Comment: @MichaelClark - agreed, but that would depend on the price point too...

Comment: Access. Can you get your subject, and equipment in and out easily. What if it's raining? Where can rentals be parked during the session? Will the equipment be secure during the move in and out.

Comment: @Stan - Good point -the proposal is for a large multi-studio drive-in setup, huge area with room to get a bus into the infinity cove, plenty of storage room during shoots. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I used to hire a lot of diferent types of studios! it depends obviously on whats being shot, who your client is, what the budget is etc.
Having a studio with a large up and over infinity cove for cars and trucks is great but you must keep it busy for obvious reasons, could also have small table top studio as well, changing rooms for models, office for meetings, kitchen for food photography. assistants for hire with the studio can be usefull! Lots of tungston lighting for the cove users.
I even used to just hire an empty commercial unit and hire lighting sometimes if it was a long shoot!
Important things I used to concider:  Good pub nearbye, comfortable and smart looking studio (if the client was comeing to the shoot), good access to motorways, rail services etc

Comment: lots of tungsten? you surprise me - i though they all wanted these HID lamps these days...!